# Problems with Huawei E3372h USB Modem

Tags: usb, modem

I have been trying to connect to the Internet with this Huawei E3372h modem for a couple of days now. I have tried everything from `sakis3g` , `wvdial` , `qmi-network` to `modemmanger` , `networkmanager` but everything fails. `ifconfig` shows a `wwan0` network when the modem is connected.

```
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:3a:ff:28:b4:51
          inet6 addr: fe80::de3:879:29a5:e625/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4408 (4.3 KiB)
```

If I try to connect to it , this is what I get

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo ifup wwan0
wwan-helper: Unsupported WWAN device: 12d1:157c
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/local-wwan-helper exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wwan0.
```

`ls /dev/` also shows a `cdc-wdm0` device (but no `ttyUSBx` device) . when I try to connect to it , this is what I get:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
Loading profile...
    APN: airtelgprs.com
Starting network with 'qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wds-start-network=airtelgprs.com  --client-no-release-cid'...
error: couldn't create client for the 'wds' service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out
error: network start failed, client not allocated
```

I am starting to doubt , the problem has go to do with the firmware of this device . Because , It works without any manual configuration when connected to a windows PC and on an  Ubuntu. It just doesn't work with the Pi . What am I doing wrong? Should I change the firmware or something? Any solutions?

Comment: Please do not post the same question again.  If you are not getting help here with the problem, you need to look elsewhere.  As already mentioned, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) will be the best place in the SE network to ask about this.  Make sure you go into detail about *everything* you have done; your [current version](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79377/5538) of this is likely to be ignored there since, e.g., it asks  "What might be the problem?" but **no problem is mentioned**.  Further, there is no mention of what you have already investigated.

Comment: It is mentioned in the title itself.

Comment: The problem is "4G LTE modem detected as WiFi Modem"?  Why is that a problem? (I don't really want an answer since I cannot help you any further, my point is that the more you leave it up to other people to drag information out of you, the more likely they are to not bother trying to help).  Further:  You're wrong, see my comment on the other question.